# How to solve the limit using the fundamental limit? (without L'Hopital's rule)

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

How to solve the following limit:

$\lim_\limits{h\to\frac{\pi}{2}}\dfrac{\cot h}{h-\frac{\pi}{2}}$

Using this fundamental limit:

$\lim_\limits{h\to0}\dfrac{\sin h}{h}=1$

I can't use L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Save Days, if you write in your post what you have tried, I could help you, otherwise moderators will close your question. Please click on [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and read it.

Comment: @Angelo, I could not identify what is wrong with my question. Please, can you explain to me?

Comment: Save Days, you should do what [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) says, please click on it and read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the change of variables $t=h-\frac{\pi}{2}$ to get
$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cot(h)}{h-\frac{\pi}{2}}=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{-\sin(t)}{t\cos(t)}=-1
$$

Comment: I understand it now, thank you so much.